# Operator Precedence && and?

Tags: php, operator-precedence

Am I reading https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php that && binds tighter than ??  ?

Why the heck would a construct that's designed to provide a "default value" of an optional array element not bind very tightly to that element?

```php
$ok = $ok && $someArray['optionalElement'] ?? true;      // Wrong
$ok = $ok && ( $someArray['optionalElement'] ?? true );  // Right
```

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP Docs

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

From this, the null coalescor treats everything to it's left as an expression argument to `isset()`

So `$ok && $someArray['optionalElement']` is taken as a full expression.

Wrapping `( $someArray['optionalElement'] ?? true )` in parentheses causes only `$someArray['optionalElement']` to be the expression and so it works as you would expect.